# The operation 'Create Declaration / Definition' could not be completed: code element is read only

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am developing a C++ project with CMake build system in Visual Studio 2015 on Win10 64bit.

I used to create function definitions in C++ file by clicking on the declaration in the header and then `Quick Actions and Refactorings`->`Create Declaration / Definition`.

For some reason this feature does not work in my project anymore. Whenever I try to use "Create Definition" I get this error message:

```
The operation 'Create Declaration / Definition' could not be completed for the following reason:

Add/Remove operation is impossible, because the code element 'NameOfClass' is read only
```

[image: error]

Also, when I choose `Quick Actions and Refactorings` small popup window appears with just two options:

[image: two options window]

When this feature works VS usually shows window with four options, like this:

[image: four options window]

I know there are tons of similar questions on SO, but none of the seem to address this particular error. I've tried everything suggested so far:

- Reboot VS and Windows
- Clean solution
- Delete the build folder entirely (with all the .suo and .user files and hidden directories) and re-create it with CMake
- Delete the content of `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
- Look in the `.err.` file in directory `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` - no relevant errors.
- Reset all VS user data using `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
- Close all other editors, explorer windows etc.

None of this has any effect.

This feature is great and the issue is very annoying. If anyone has any clue, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I had a mistake in CMake scripts, that's why some of the header files were not included in the Visual Studio project. If you have this error make sure both `.cpp` and `.hpp` files are added to your VS project files.

Comment: Hi Alex, since you already solved your issue by yourself and thanks for sharing, it is better to mark it as answer, that will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this useful workaround.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Sorry, but how do I do this exactly? I cannot yet mark answer as accepted because only 1 day passed since I answered. Or do you mean mark the whole question?

Comment: Hi Alex, after 24 hours when you posted the reply, you can mark it. If it have not reach 24 hours, I'm so sorry to trouble you, it just a reminder:)